# Replace two nested sub queries with one sub query or refactoring query with more appropriate query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data like the following. Here I am showing just data but in actual this data comes from several tables by joining.

```
CREATE TABLE project_complete_data (PROJECT_ID, PROJ_COMPANY_NAME,  PROJECT_NAME,           CUSTOM_LOT_NO,          TASK_NAME,                              TASK_ACTUAL_END_DATE,   TASK_FINISH_DATE,   TASK_FINISHED,  TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,    TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_TIME,                                       PO_TOTAL_AMOUNT ,   PO_STATUS,  PO_TYPE) AS
                        SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    '01a',                  'Rough-In Plumbing',                    DATE '2009-12-17',      DATE '2014-09-01',  1,              null,                       null,                                                               0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    '02',                   'Update Lender Info in BT - Sales Rep', DATE '2005-06-28',      DATE '2005-10-11',  1,              null,                       null,                                                               0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    '020',                  'TK task',                              DATE '2018-11-07',      DATE '2019-06-21',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:12:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            33,                 100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    '152',                  'HVAC rough',                           DATE '2021-09-16',      DATE '2021-08-05',  1,              DATE '2021-08-05',          TO_DATE('2021-08-05 18:40:05', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'New task 1',                           DATE '2021-12-10',      DATE '2021-12-15',  0,              DATE '2021-12-10',          TO_DATE('2021-12-10 19:27:47', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            4,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'New task 2',                           DATE '2021-12-12',      DATE '2021-12-16',  0,              DATE '2021-12-12',          TO_DATE('2021-12-12 19:27:47', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            5,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Install Countertops',                  DATE '2019-04-25',      DATE '2021-08-04',  1,              DATE '2021-08-04',          TO_DATE('2021-08-04 19:27:47', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Inspection: Backfill',                 DATE '2019-02-08',      DATE '2021-08-04',  1,              DATE '2021-08-04',          TO_DATE('2021-08-04 19:27:47', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Backfill',                             DATE '2019-02-11',      DATE '2019-06-10',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 20:47:51', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Set Foundation Walls',                 DATE '2019-02-01',      DATE '2019-02-01',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:22:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Dig and Form Footing',                 DATE '2019-01-24',      DATE '2019-01-23',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:21:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            5,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Pour Footing',                         DATE '2019-01-29',      DATE '2019-01-29',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:18:26', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            5,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Excavate Foundation',                  DATE '2019-01-22',      DATE '2019-01-22',  1,              DATE '2019-06-19',          TO_DATE('2019-06-19 18:15:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*',  'Stake out Foundation Lot',             DATE '2019-01-21',      DATE '2019-01-21',  1,              DATE '2019-06-19',          TO_DATE('2019-06-19 17:25:35', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Finalize Test 2',      'HVAC rough',                           DATE '2019-01-11',      DATE '2021-08-03',  1,              DATE '2021-08-03',          TO_DATE('2021-08-03 20:32:55', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Finalize Test 2',      'first floor framing',                  DATE '2018-11-30',      DATE '2018-11-26',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 23:24:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Finalize Test 2',      'second floor framing',                 DATE '2018-12-07',      DATE '2018-10-29',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 23:18:38', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 4',              'Excavate Foundation',                  DATE '2018-11-02',      DATE '2018-11-05',  1,              DATE '2019-06-21',          TO_DATE('2019-06-21 18:28:51', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'New task 1',                           DATE '2021-12-08',      DATE '2021-12-11',  0,              DATE '2021-12-08',          TO_DATE('2021-12-08 20:42:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            6,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'New task 2',                           DATE '2021-12-09',      DATE '2021-12-12',  0,              DATE '2021-12-09',          TO_DATE('2021-12-09 20:42:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            12,                 100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'electrical rough',                     DATE '2019-08-15',      DATE '2021-08-03',  1,              DATE '2021-08-03',          TO_DATE('2021-08-03 20:42:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'HVAC rough',                           DATE '2019-08-27',      DATE '2021-08-03',  1,              DATE '2021-08-03',          TO_DATE('2021-08-03 20:42:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            12,                 100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'first floor framing',                  DATE '2019-08-22',      DATE '2021-07-19',  1,              DATE '2021-07-19',          TO_DATE('2021-07-19 15:52:38', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'first floor framing',                  DATE '2019-08-22',      DATE '2021-07-19',  1,              DATE '2021-07-19',          TO_DATE('2021-07-19 15:52:38', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Lot # 8',              'second floor framing',                 DATE '2019-09-03',      DATE '2019-06-17',  1,              DATE '2019-06-20',          TO_DATE('2019-06-20 20:41:04', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  100,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'Orange Star',          'cabinet-task',                         DATE '2018-04-02',      DATE '2018-05-15',  1,              DATE '2018-05-15',          TO_DATE('2018-05-15 15:12:03', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 511,         'A Inc.',           'A',                    'A test lot',           'first floor framing',                  DATE '2021-05-28',      DATE '2021-07-30',  1,              DATE '2021-07-30',          TO_DATE('2021-07-30 19:03:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 3247,        'B Inc.',           'B',                    '01/002.B',             'first floor framing',                  DATE '2021-07-30',      DATE '2021-09-20',  1,              DATE '2021-09-20',          TO_DATE('2021-09-20 16:19:53', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),            0,                  101,        100 FROM DUAL;
```

Now I have to get the last completed task. Also I need to `sum po_total_amount` based on some condition for all the same lots. And then calculate the percentage. And finally show the one last modified task with these sum and percentage.

I came up with the following nested query

```
Select project_name,
custom_lot_no as "Lot#",
task_name AS "Last Completed Task with a PO",
task_actual_end_date as "Task Actual End Date",
TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED as "Total POs Completed",
TOTAL_COMMITED as "Total Committed",
Round(NVL((TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED / NULLIF(TOTAL_COMMITED, 0)) ,0) * 100) || '%' AS "% Completed"
from(
    select project_id, 
        project_name,
        custom_lot_no,
        task_name,
        task_actual_end_date,
        SUM(pos_completed) OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, TASK_FINISHED) AS TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED,
        SUM(committed) OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, TASK_FINISHED) AS TOTAL_COMMITED,
        last_modified_date_time,
        last_task_finish_seq
    from (
        select 
            project_id,
            proj_company_name,
            project_name,       
            custom_lot_no, 
            task_name,
            NVL(to_char(task_actual_end_date), ' ') AS TASK_ACTUAL_END_DATE,
            task_finish_date AS TASK_FINISH_DATE,
            task_finished AS TASK_FINISHED,
            to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as last_modified_date_time,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, task_finished ORDER BY to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc) AS LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ,
                po_total_amount,
                po_status,
                CASE 
                    WHEN po_status = 101 THEN po_total_amount   
                    ELSE 0
                END as POs_COMPLETED,
                po_type,
                CASE 
                    WHEN po_type = 100 THEN po_total_amount 
                    ELSE 0
                END as "COMMITTED"
        FROM project_complete_data
        order by project_name, custom_lot_no, to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc
    )
    where task_finished = 1
    order by project_name, custom_lot_no, last_modified_date_time desc
)
where last_task_finish_seq = 1;
```

But as you can see there is a nested query and inside there is another query. Although it is getting the results but it is looking weird.

Can I reduce it to just one nested query or is there another way to write the same query without nesting.

Actually I stuck in the inner most query while trying to find the sum there. If I use

```
CASE 
    WHEN po_status = 101 THEN SUM(po_total_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, task_finished ORDER BY to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc) 
    ELSE 0
END as TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED,
```

Then for lot `Bldg C1|Parcel 01&*` I get the sum at `last_task_finish_seq = 5`. And if I use in outer query `where last_task_finish_seq = 1`. Then I get the sum 0. Because `last_task_finish_seq = 1` has sum 0.

If some how I calculate the sum and percentage inside the inner most nested query or on the data that I provided above. Then one nested query will automatically remove.

How can I remove the one nested query or write this query without any sub query ?

Following is the actual query that gets all the data that I showed above. So basically this is my inner most nested query. I put all the data in a table above so it can be run easily.

```
select 
        poh.project_id,
        cp.proj_company_name,
        cp.project_name,        
        u.custom_lot_no, 
        st.task_name, 
        NVL(to_char(st.original_finish_date), ' ') AS TASK_ACTUAL_END_DATE,                                                 -- Task Actual End date
        st.finish_date AS TASK_FINISH_DATE,
        st.is_finished AS TASK_FINISHED,
        st.last_modified_date AS TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
        to_char(st.last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AS TASK_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_TIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.custom_lot_no, st.is_finished ORDER BY to_char(st.last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc) AS LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ,
        poh.po_total_amount,
        poh.po_status,
        CASE 
            WHEN (poh.po_status = 101) THEN poh.po_total_amount       -- Approved PO
            ELSE 0
        END as POs_COMPLETED,
        poh.po_type,
        CASE 
            WHEN (poh.po_type = 100) THEN poh.po_total_amount         -- System Generated PO
            ELSE 0
        END as "COMMITTED"
    FROM po_header poh                          
    inner join unit u on poh.unit_id = u.unit_id                    -- POs must be created for a lot to populate on this report 
    inner join schedule s on u.con_schedule_id = s.schedule_id              
    inner join company_project cp on poh.project_id = cp.project_id 
    inner join company_project_setting cps on cp.project_id = cps.project_id
    inner join po_header_status_lk pohslk on poh.po_status = pohslk.code 
    LEFT JOIN schedule_task st on poh.schedule_task_id = st.schedule_task_id 
    LEFT join schedule s on st.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
    WHERE poh.company_id =  653 
    AND poh.po_type = 100                       -- Only System Generated POs
    AND poh.po_status in ('100', '101')         -- PO Must be open (100) and approved (101)
    AND u.status_id in ('102', '103')           -- Only Include Lots that are Construction Status: In Production (102) or Completed(103)
    And s.status = 101                          -- A schedule must be approved
    AND (
        CASE
                WHEN  (cps.construction_type  = 0 and st.is_finished = 1 and (poh.schedule_task_id is not null or poh.schedule_task_id > 0) )THEN -9999
                WHEN  (cps.construction_type in ('1', '2')) THEN -9999
            END
    ) = -9999
    order by cp.project_name, u.custom_lot_no, to_char(st.last_modified_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc
```

Thanks

Comment: Subqueries at several nesting levels are not uncommon, why do you think that's weird? What is done usually is to write the successive subqueries, starting from the innermost one(s) and out to the final SELECT, in the `WITH` clause at the top. Each subquery can then reference the previous ones. Separate question: why do you need to show % completed as zero, when total committed is zero? Shouldn't that be better shown as NULL? As it is, you can't distinguish between "none committed" on the one hand, and "0 of 12" on the other hand, even though in most cases those would be viewed as different.

Comment: @mathguy I asked to reduce this nesting by my senior that's why I am doing it. I don't have any problem with the query. In one of my report I had to sum all the percentages in the column. May be same requirement can come for this report too. That's why I used 0 instead of null. So I can add all the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce to one sub query

```
Select project_name,
custom_lot_no as "Lot#",
task_name AS "Last Completed Task with a PO",
task_actual_end_date as "Task Actual End Date",
TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED as "Total POs Completed",
TOTAL_COMMITED as "Total Committed",
Round(NVL((TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED / NULLIF(TOTAL_COMMITED, 0)) ,0) * 100) || '%' AS "% Completed"
from(
    select 
        project_id,
        proj_company_name,
        project_name,       
        custom_lot_no, 
        task_name,
        NVL(to_char(task_actual_end_date), ' ') AS TASK_ACTUAL_END_DATE,
        task_finish_date AS TASK_FINISH_DATE,
        task_finished AS TASK_FINISHED,
        to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as last_modified_date_time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, task_finished ORDER BY to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc) AS LAST_TASK_FINISH_SEQ,
        po_total_amount,
        po_status,
        CASE 
            WHEN po_status = 101 THEN po_total_amount   
            ELSE 0
        END as POs_COMPLETED,
        SUM(
            CASE 
                WHEN po_status = 101 THEN po_total_amount 
                ELSE 0 
            END
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, task_finished) AS TOTAL_POS_COMPLETED,
        po_type,
        CASE 
            WHEN po_type = 100 THEN po_total_amount 
            ELSE 0
        END as "COMMITTED",
        SUM(
            CASE 
                WHEN po_type = 100 THEN po_total_amount 
                ELSE 0 
            END
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY custom_lot_no, task_finished) AS TOTAL_COMMITED
    FROM project_complete_data
    order by project_name, custom_lot_no, to_char(task_last_modified_date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') desc
)where last_task_finish_seq = 1 and task_finished = 1;
```